# Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I need to concatenate two dataframes `df_a` and `df_b` that have equal number of rows (`nRow`) horizontally without any consideration of keys. This function is similar to `cbind` in the **R programming language**. The number of columns in each dataframe may be different.

The resultant dataframe will have the same number of rows `nRow` and number of columns equal to the sum of number of columns in both the dataframes. In other words, this is a blind columnar concatenation of two dataframes.

```py
import pandas as pd
dict_data = {'Treatment': ['C', 'C', 'C'], 'Biorep': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Techrep': [1, 1, 1], 'AAseq': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'], 'mz':[500.0, 500.5, 501.0]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
dict_data = {'Treatment1': ['C', 'C', 'C'], 'Biorep1': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Techrep1': [1, 1, 1], 'AAseq1': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'], 'inte1':[1100.0, 1050.0, 1010.0]}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

call [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and pass param `axis=1` to concatenate column-wise:

```
In [5]:

pd.concat([df_a,df_b], axis=1)
Out[5]:
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz      AAseq1 Biorep1  Techrep1  \
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.5  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   

  Treatment1  inte1  
0          C   1100  
1          C   1050  
2          C   1010
```

There is a useful guide to the various methods of [merging, joining and concatenating](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) online.

For example, as you have no clashing columns you can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) and use the indices as they have the same number of rows:

```
In [6]:

df_a.merge(df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
Out[6]:
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz      AAseq1 Biorep1  Techrep1  \
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.5  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   

  Treatment1  inte1  
0          C   1100  
1          C   1050  
2          C   1010
```

And for the same reasons as above a simple [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) works too:

```
In [7]:

df_a.join(df_b)
Out[7]:
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz      AAseq1 Biorep1  Techrep1  \
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.5  ELVISLIVES       A         1   
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0  ELVISLIVES       A         1   

  Treatment1  inte1  
0          C   1100  
1          C   1050  
2          C   1010
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @EdChum
I was struggling with same problem especially when indexes do not match. Unfortunatly in pandas guide this case is missed (when you for example delete some rows)

```
import pandas as pd
t=pd.DataFrame()
t['a']=[1,2,3,4]
t=t.loc[t['a']>1] #now index starts from 1

u=pd.DataFrame()
u['b']=[1,2,3] #index starts from 0

#option 1
#keep index of t
u.index = t.index 

#option 2
#index of t starts from 0
t.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

#now concat will keep number of rows 
r=pd.concat([t,u], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the index labels are different (e.g., if `df_a.index == [0, 1, 2]` and `df_b.index == [10, 20, 30]` are `True`), a straightforward `join` (or `concat` or `merge`) may produce NaN rows. A useful method in that case is `set_axis()` that coerces the indices to be the same.

```py
concatenated_df = df_a.join(df_b.set_axis(df_a.index))
# or 
concatenated_df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b.set_axis(df_a.index)], axis=1)
```

---

If the length of the frames are the same, then you can also assign `df_b` to `df_a`. Unlike `concat` (or `join` or `merge`), this alters `df_a` and doesn't create a new dataframe.

```py
df_a[df_b.columns] = df_b

# if index labels are different
df_a[df_b.columns] = df_b.set_axis(df_a.index)
```