# how to merge data frames with same format in python

Tags: python, pandas

Looked at other similar questions, but none has the use case I have.
I have multiple files with the same format and no header

```
file1
id, value 
1, 100
2, 150 
...

file2
10, 500
11, 510
....
```

I would like to "merge" them to have

```
id, value
1, 100
2, 150
...
10, 500
11, 510
...
```

tried merge, append, concat but couldn't achieve the end result I am looking for.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','value'])
df2.columns = ['id','value']
for file_name in os.listdir(work_dir):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(work_dir+'/'+file_name, header=None)
    df1.columns = ['id','value']
    df2 = pd.merge(df2,df1, on ='id')
```

Or any other suggestion to load multiple files in to a data frame appreciated. I do have another data frame coming from a db will be merged same way so merge is a question too.

Comment: That is not a `merge` but an `append` (very important semantics in data analysis world). Also, your post suggests the first file does have headers and all else doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for append. Try this:

```
df1.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` should also work for you. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

You should also name each column upon import...

`pd.read_csv(work_dir+'/'+file_name, header=None, names=['id', 'value'])`

See [Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: concat is giving me multiple columns, instead of two

Comment: You might need to also add ‘axis=1’ in the method call