# How to rearrange separate dataframes and join them into a single summary dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have the following dataframes:

```py
result=pd.DataFrame({'BID':1.87,'ASK':1.95},index=[0])

result1=pd.DataFrame({'BID':1.95,'ASK':2.05},index=[0])

result2=pd.DataFrame({'BID':1.95,'ASK':2.065},index=[0])

result.index.name='nok'

result1.index.name='sek'

result2.index.name='dkk'
```

I need to have those dataframes in a summary dataframe which looks like the below, with currency being the index name from the previous dataframe, and bid and ask need assigned to the respective columns.:

[image]

I attempted to create an empty dataframe:

```py
summary=pd.DataFrame(columns=['CURRENCY','BID','ASK'])
```

and tried to append the values but it did not work.

```py
summary=summary.append({'CURRENCY':result.index.name,'BID':result['BID'],'ASK':result['ASK']})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: hey i saw this now but where it is different is that i need additional column called currency to which the value of the index name from the previous dataframes is assigned so simply concatenating does not work and that currency name cannot be the index.

Comment: i wonder why did you create df like `result=pd.DataFrame({'BID':1.87,'ASK':1.95},index=[0])` instead of `result=pd.DataFrame({'BID':1.87,'ASK':1.95},index=['nok'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested before, you can concatenate the dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat([result, result1, result2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

With ignore_index=True this is your print:

```
        BID    ASK
    0  1.87  1.950
    1  1.95  2.050
    2  1.95  2.065
```

Useful if you want to reference the data in this new dataframe. Otherwise:

```
df = pd.concat([result, result1, result2], axis=0)
```

Then, recreate the currency labels.

```
 idx = 0   
 df.insert(loc =idx,column = '',value=['nok','sek','dkk'])

 print(df)
         BID    ASK
 0  nok  1.87  1.950
 1  sek  1.95  2.050
 2  dkk  1.95  2.065
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `Pandas.concat()` method. It takes a list of dataframes to concatanate, and the `axis = 0/1) argument that determines whether to do it by rows or columns, respectively.

However, you can skip that by making your `DataFrame` all arranged to begin with, by creating an appropriate dictionary:

```py
df_dict = {'NOK' : {'BID':1.87,'ASK':1.95},
           'SEK' : {'BID':1.95,'ASK':2.05},
           'DKK' : {'BID':1.95,'ASK':2.065}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict, orient = 'index')
```

The `orient` argument determines your initial values are rows (columns by default).