# How to merge same day's datas and add as a new column in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge, aggregation

I have a dataframe like this:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2buG.png

I want to merge the same day's readings then plus them and add a new column as day_total_read, how can i do that ?

For example indexs 2-3,  8-9,  10-11

Comment: You could use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly certain how you're going to have a new column in the current table, since you'll be having an aggregate over a couple rows, and it won't be a one-to-one mapping of rows. Overall, though, you're pretty much describing a groupby operation.

Assuming `df` is your dataframe, `df.groupby("date").sum()` should do the trick just fine.

This'll return a new dataframe though, so if you want to merge it back into the original dataframe as a new column (like I said, won't be one-to-one, so there will be duplicates here) you'd probably wanna just [column-wise append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas), or something like that

[Here's](https://repl.it/@EnochKumala/ImperturbableUnknownTelevision) an example of it at work

Comment: It worked and duplicated as you said, is there a way to get rid of duplicates and show two same row as one ?

Comment: I've added a repl link here, not really sure what you're saying that there are duplicates. If you just purely use the command, you should be seeing the rows grouped as one

Comment: For no duplicates, you can use the `new_df` version, and if you want to merge it back, it's `merged_df`