# how to add a data frame to an other data frame as new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a data frame with 41 columns (and n rows). i want to add another data frame to main data frame (as new columns). the new data frame that should add to the main can have different numbers of column but have same number of rows with main data frame.for example:

[image]

new data frame should be:

[image]

is there any function to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new column to existing DataFrame in Python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555323/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-python-pandas)

Comment: ``pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1) ``

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pd.concat:

```
new_df = pd.concat([main_df,second_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you tagged pandas (pd), so assuming you are using that, you can use:

```
pd.merge('main data frame', 'second data frame', left_index=True)
```