# proper implementation of pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

```
concat = pd.concat([data_1, data_2])
```

above code works on multiple CSVs but it duplicates the column
tried reset_index and axis=0 but no good.

all CSVs have 21 columns but the code gives me 42 columns after concat

Any suggestions, ideas, comments are much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting concatenate horizontally or vertically?  What is this duplicated column?  What does `data_1` and `data_2` look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: all CSVs have 21 columns but the code gives me 42 columns after concat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `axis=1` . It will concatenate column wise.

```
concat = pd.concat([data_1, data_2], axis =1)
```

Comment: tried it, still no good. not sure why

Comment: Can you please share the code and dataset?

Comment: try this 
`
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
`
It will remove duplicate columns

Comment: or if you have 2 csv files, you may also go for `concat = pd.merge(data_1, data_2, how='inner')'

Answer (score -2):

Convert them to numpy array and then concat using hstack and vstack