# How to take transpose of one particular DataFrame column in Python? Also how to get certain values from second iteration onwards from 'for' loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am running a 'for' loop whose output is a data frame with two columns, column 1 with columns names and column 2 with data. It can be seen below:

[image]

Next, I would take the transpose of this data like this:

[image]

In the next iteration again I would get the similar data(with 2 columns as the first table) for which I don't need columns data, just data should append to the data from the first iteration as seen:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate rows of two dataframes in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135436/concatenate-rows-of-two-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: @Thekingis007 Concat is not working, it is copying the column name as well

Answer (score -1):

For your first question first set your index to you desired column names column, then transpose using `T`:

`df2=df.set_index('1').T`

```
1   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
2   data_1_1    data_1_2    data_1_3    data_1_4    data_1_5
```